# resolve metaMDS error : "veg_distance" not available for .C() for package "vegan"

Tags: r, distance, vegan, mds

I keep getting the following error when trying to run `metaMDS()` from the `vegan` package:

```
my_mds <- vegan::metaMDS(df_species, distance="bray", k=2, trymax=1000, autotransform=TRUE)


Error in .C("veg_distance", x = as.double(x), nr = N, nc = ncol(x), d = double(N *  :  
"veg_distance" not available for .C() for package "vegan"
```

I have tried:
   1. searching online for this error - which yields zero results
   2. reducing the size of my data frame to 17 rows and 12 columns
   3. clearing all packages from Global Environment to eliminate potential package conflicts
   4. specifying `vegan::metaMDS`

Nothing has worked.  Can you help provide a solution to this error?

Example data is here:

```
structure(list(Species_1 = c(68.75, 51.4583333333333, 67.1666666666667, 
36.3333333333333, 37.1666666666667, 45, 34.25, 20.9583333333333, 
41.75, 85.7272727272727, 63.5, 27.1666666666667, 59.5, 76.75, 
50.1666666666667, 35.25, 42), Species_2 = c(21.3333333333333, 
26.2916666666667, 32.7083333333333, 36.6666666666667, 26.25, 
24.75, 27.0833333333333, 27.5, 39.3333333333333, 35, 24.0833333333333, 
18.0833333333333, 16.3333333333333, 31.75, 23.3333333333333, 
21.5, 22.8333333333333), Species_3 = c(11.6666666666667,     7.66666666666667, 
18.0416666666667, 36.85, 50.6666666666667, 45.9166666666667, 
48.5833333333333, 16.0833333333333, 15.9166666666667, 17.2727272727273, 
11.8333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 1.95833333333333, 1.04166666666667, 
6.45833333333333, 7.70833333333333, 9.41666666666667), Species_4 = c(2.5, 
3.25, 2.25, 3.375, 6.70833333333333, 11.3333333333333, 7.70833333333333, 
4.04166666666667, 8.58333333333333, 4.72727272727273, 0.916666666666667, 
1.45833333333333, 1.375, 2.54166666666667, 1.75, 4.79166666666667, 
3.58333333333333), Species_5 = c(2.5, 7.41666666666667, 14.25, 
4.45833333333333, 5.66666666666667, 9.04166666666667, 5.54166666666667, 
5, 6.41666666666667, 3.59090909090909, 2.54166666666667,     2.66666666666667, 
2.25, 2.25, 1.75, 2.83333333333333, 4.16666666666667), Species_6 =     c(0.0833333333333333, 
0.458333333333333, 0.0416666666666667, 0.5, 0.458333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 11.9583333333333,     0.208333333333333, 
0, 0.125, 2.29166666666667, 24.7916666666667, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 
0.708333333333333, 0.166666666666667), Species_7 = c(1.5,     2.45833333333333, 
2.41666666666667, 2.125, 3.33333333333333, 2.45833333333333, 
2.95833333333333, 4.16666666666667, 1.5, 1.63636363636364, 1.375, 
2.04166666666667, 1, 1.04166666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2, 2
), Species_8 = c(1.20833333333333, 3.45833333333333, 1.75,     1.20833333333333, 
0.958333333333333, 0.791666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
1.83333333333333, 0.909090909090909, 0.583333333333333, 1.91666666666667, 
0.75, 1.20833333333333, 0.791666666666667, 2.08333333333333, 
0.583333333333333), Species_9 = c(0.125, 0.208333333333333, 1.58333333333333, 
0.375, 0.0416666666666667, 0.916666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 1.25, 0.363636363636364, 0.625, 0.25,  0.291666666666667, 
0.375, 0.291666666666667, 0.25, 0.208333333333333), Species_10 =   c(0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0833333333333333, 0.25, 0.208333333333333, 
0.0416666666666667, 0.625, 0.166666666666667, 0.0909090909090909, 
0.166666666666667, 0.25, 0.166666666666667, 0.208333333333333, 
0.125, 0.583333333333333, 0.0833333333333333), Species_11 = c(0.125, 
0.0416666666666667, 0.0833333333333333, 0.458333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0416666666666667, 0, 0.0416666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0454545454545455, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.291666666666667, 0, 0.291666666666667, 0.333333333333333), Species_12 = c(0, 0, 0.416666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), .Names = c("Species_1", 
"Species_2", "Species_3", "Species_4", "Species_5", "Species_6", 
"Species_7", "Species_8", "Species_9", "Species_10", "Species_11", 
"Species_12"))
```

Session info:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0     MASS_7.3-47     vegan_2.4-3     lattice_0.20-35     permute_0.9-4  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10     assertthat_0.2.0 grid_3.4.0       R6_2.2.0             nlme_3.1-131     DBI_0.6-1       
 [7] magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.2.0   Matrix_1.2-10    tools_3.4.0         parallel_3.4.0   compiler_3.4.0  
[13] cluster_2.0.6    mgcv_1.8-17      tibble_1.3.0
```

Comment: Works for me. My `sessionInfo()` `R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`

Comment: `attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] vegan_2.4-2     lattice_0.20-34 permute_0.9-4  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] MASS_7.3-45    Matrix_1.2-7.1 parallel_3.3.3 tools_3.3.3    mgcv_1.8-15    gtable_0.2.0   nlme_3.1-128   grid_3.3.3    
[9] cluster_2.0.4 `

Comment: Thanks for trying J.Con.  There are some differences between your system and mine.  Since posting, I've tried the code on my organization's server, and it works.  I will likely file a bug issue with vegan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-install vegan. R version 3.4.0 is binary-incompatible with R 3.3.x and all packages with compiled code must be re-installed in R 3.4.0.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks Jari. I'll try that.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am encountering the same error with vegan and re-installing did not help

Comment: this is probably a different issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882886/make-network-error-in-r-error-veg-distance-not-available-for-c-for-packag