# Error in loading the library for vegan

Tags: r, vegan

I installed the new version of vegan (and permute, it seemed to not work with the older version I had), but I don't manage to load the library anymore.

I get this error (sorry for french part of the message):

Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  impossible de charger l'objet partagé (translation : impossible to load the shared object) 
'/Users/Lise/Library/R/3.1/library/vegan/libs/vegan.so':
  dlopen(/Users/Lise/Library/R/3.1/library/vegan/libs/vegan.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Lise/Library/R/3.1/library/vegan/libs/vegan.so
  Reason: image not found
De plus : Message d'avis :
le package ‘vegan’ a été compilé avec la version R 3.3.2 (the package 'vegan' has been complied with the version R.3.3.2)
Erreur : le chargement du package ou de l'espace de noms a échoué pour ‘vegan’ (the loading of the package or of the name space has failed for 'vegan')

I'm on mac OS X Sierra, I reinstalled rstudio, vegan and permute. Do you have any ideas why it's not working anymore? I'm sorry I'm a beginner on R.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Which version of R do you have? It loads without problem on my Mac Sierra, with R 3.4.2.

Comment: It is perhaps a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010681/resolve-metamds-error-veg-distance-not-available-for-c-for-package-vegan

Comment: I have rstudio 1.1.383. i already installed again Rstudio, vegan and permute, should I delete Rstudio and libraries, and start from zero?

Answer (score 0):

To check if this is just binary incompatible pkgs you can get R to check if the packages were built under an older version of R and reinstall those that are.

Use:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
```

and go make a cup of your beverage of choice as it might take a while to complete the reinstallation.