# Make_network error in R Error - "veg_distance" not available for .C() for package "vegan"

Tags: r, vegan

I'm getting an error when running make_work from the "vegan" R package:

```
net <- make_network(ps)

Error in .C("veg_distance", x = as.double(x), nr = N, nc = ncol(x), d = double(N *  : 
"veg_distance" not available for .C() for package "vegan"
```

Here is my sesion info:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] vegan_2.5-1             lattice_0.20-35         permute_0.9-4          
[4] phyloseqGraphTest_0.0.1 ggplot2_2.2.1           phyloseq_1.22.3
```

I've seen the other cases related to this error, which advised to uninstall and re-install vegan, which I did (hence the recent update to the package), to no avail.

Comment: Firstly, there is no command `make_work()` or `make_network()` in **vegan**: you must be using some other package. Secondly, `veg_distance()` cannot be called like that in vegan_2.5-1 (it needs `.Call()` instead of `.C()`). Thirdly, you should not call the compiled code from your package, but you should call the **R** function `vegan::vegdist()`. You seem to have a problem with some external package or script. Both CRAN and we checked the vegan 2.5-1 does not break dependent packages, but check the package from which your found `make_network()` command.

Comment: @JariOksanen I'm pretty sure this (calling C code from outside a pkg) is not allowed by CRAN and hasn't been for a very long time.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I was thinking the same, but it happened... and I was baffled. The error message had a call `.C("veg_distance", ...)` although there was no such a line in **vegan** 2.5-1. I assumed it was in some other function. However, the situation seems to be that when **vegan** was upgraded to 2.5-1, **phyloseq** kept **R** functions of older **vegan** (2.4-x) and did not upgrade them. The compiled library was still upgraded and there is a mismatch between compiled library and **phyloseq** copies of **vegan** functions. I don't know if this copy was made in build, install or load time.

Comment: @GavinSimpson it seems that when you make a S4 generic from a function in another package, the original function is made as the default method for that new S4 generic. When you build a binary or install that new package with the S4 generic, the original function is copied to the new package. So there was a copy of 2.4-6 version of vegan::vegdist in phyloseq, and when vegan was upgraded to 2.5-1 the compiled library changed to 2.5-1 interface, and the old phyloseq version failed.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an issue with **phyloseq** interacting with **vegan** internals -- at least a similar issue has been reported both in **vegan** and in **phyloseq** in github. The alternatives seem to be:

1. You can try if re-installing **phyloseq** (to the same version) after **vegan** 2.5-1 update will help: it seems that **phyloseq** saves the **vegan** function when it is installed or built (either, I don't know), and it will use that private version even when **vegan** changes.
2. Downgrade **vegan** to 2.4-6 which is the newest version with the old internals (that were also used in **phyloseq**).
3. Wait till the issue is fixed in **phyloseq**.
4. If possible, try to find a way to go around the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I attempted to install and reinstall phyloseq, to no avail. I am going to attempt the downgrade next, and if not, try to find another work around. 

I appreciate the response!

Comment: You need to install **phyloseq** from the source files. If you cannot do, you must wait till a new build version of **phyloseq** is published in the Bioconductor. While waiting, you only choice is to downgrade **vegan** to version 2.4-6 that is compatible with your **phyloseq**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with another function from phyloseq, ordinate()), and think I got it to work. People discussed it in great detail: https://github.com/joey711/phyloseq/issues/921. I'll leave here what has worked for me, after reading cjfields's advice on the page linked above.

```
# First get stringi straight
install.packages("stringi", configure.args="--disable-pkg-config")
library(stringi)
packageVersion("stringi")
# Vegan
install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)
packageVersion('vegan') #should be 2.5-1 (or more recent, if someone reads this later)
# Phyloseq. Install the latest version from github (the version on other repos may still have the bug)
library("devtools")
install_github("joey711/phyloseq")
library(phyloseq)
packageVersion('phyloseq')
```

Before this, I tried downgrading vegan and installing phyloseq again, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Install `phyloseq` from github. It fixes the issue.

```
library("devtools")

install_github("joey711/phyloseq")

packageVersion('phyloseq')
```

[1] ‘1.23.1’

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that R version, but for R 3.3.3, I downgraded to vegan 2.4.2 and this solved it. I also needed to downgrade to ape 4.0 for an ape incompatibility with older phyloseq. I was unable to upgrade phyloseq with devtools due to biocgenerics 0.22 being required.